# BeforeInsert and BeforeUpdate are fired twice in grails domain class

Tags: events, grails, persistence, grails-domain-class

I am using grails version 2.1.0 in my application and i have a before insert in my domain class which encodes the password as below.

package com.valuelabs.bets.security

class SecUser {
   transient springSecurityService

```
String username
String password
String emailId
String mobileNumber
String position
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired
boolean firstTimeLogin 
String userstatus
String userRole
Date activateDate
Date expireDate = new Date()
Audit audit
static embedded = ['audit']


static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
    sort "username"
}

def beforeInsert() {
    println "in before insert"
        encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    println "in before update"
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
    audit.lastUpdated = new Date()
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    println " Before ========================> "+ password
    if(springSecurityService){
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
    println " springSecurityService "+ springSecurityService +" password "+password
}


Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
    SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
}


String toString(){
    username
    }
static transients  = ['userstatus','userRole']
```

}

Here is my controller logic

```
 if (!secUserInstance.save(flush:true)) {
        println "13"
        //secUserInstance.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
        render(view: "create", model: [secUserInstance: secUserInstance,curRole:""])
        return
    }
```

now the problem is the password is encoding twice when I save the instance.

Please let me know whether there is any problem with the grails version,if any please let me know the correct version or possible solution.

Comment: Can you please write some more code from controller and services where you write save code and also provide your domain structure.

Comment: I have changed the code briefing the domain,controller . Please look at it

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour when there are multiple dataSources defined and the domain class has `datasource 'ALL' ` in it. Even if it inserts to only one data source it still calls beforeInsert multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us your DataSource.groovy file? Be aware that GORM events are fired as many times as data sources you have in your application.